# ASP.NET Passing parameter with response.redirect without showing in url

Tags: asp.net, redirect, parameters, response

I am redirecting to a page in my asp.net application using which passes a parameter in the url.

```
 HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication) sender;
 HttpResponse response = app.Context.Response;
 app.Response.Redirect("~/auth/SignOn.aspx?capath=" + capath);
```

Is there a way to send execution or direct to that page and pass the paremeter without showing it in the url? Thanks.

Comment: You can take help of Session for that OR you can use Encrypt/Decrypt querystring parameter to perform full security.

Comment: Cheer's , Happy coding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

url parameters are very insecure. it is a simple  string that goes visible to everyone. you should either encrypt it or use sessions. if it is an id you are passing in the url, you can use uniqueidentifier as an id.

I think the best and easiest way is to send it via Sessions.

Answer (score 3):

You **can't** hide values sent in query string, but you can encrypt the values, if you want them not to be readable. OR Instead of simple redirection you will have look for other option to navigate to next page

[How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

if you website has distributed in many computer, 
you should use cookie in order to void session miss

write cookie

```
HttpCookie testCookie = new HttpCookie("capath");
    testCookie.Value = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(capath);
    Response.Cookies.Add(testCookie);
```

read cookie

```
if (Request.Cookies["capath"] != null)
    {
        HttpCookie getCookie = Request.Cookies.Get("capath");
}
```

Comment: Cookies are unreliable and 'users' can turn them off.